# Pandas GroupBy.nth function abnormal behaviour with NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let the pandas dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 2, 3],
                   'B': ["hello", "mr", "python"]})
```

I will groupby by column "A" where the first value for "A" is missing :

```
g = df.groupby("A")
```

using `g.nth(0)` I get this strange result :

```
      B
A          
2.0      mr
3.0   hello
3.0  python
```

"hello" should not appear for value A = 3.0.

However passing the parameter `dropna = "any"` to `nth` give the appropriate result i.e :

```
          B
A          
2.0      mr
3.0  python
```

I have pandas 0.19.2.

Could someone explain me the reason of this abnormality ?

Comment: You forgot to ask your question.

Comment: Fixed ! Thank you

Comment: `df.groupby("A",as_index=False).nth(0)`

Comment: also, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3729